# Space problem updating from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: updates, disk-usage

I tried updating from 19.10 to 20.04, but in the process I keep getting this warning:
(I translated the message so it might be slightly different)

> Insufficient free disk space
>
> The version upgrade has stopped: 1.780 M of free disk space is needed
>   "/ var". Free at least another 1,225 M of space on «/ var». Remove
>   temporary packages from another installation with the "sudo apt clean"
>   command.

I used the command, but after tryig again the space needed didn't change.
This is the space that the folders take in /var displayed with ls -al

```
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root      4096 mar 11 14:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root      4096 feb 19 21:57 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4096 mag  2 12:24 backups
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root      4096 feb 15 14:42 cache
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root      2708 mar 11 14:36 .com.zerog.registry.xml
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie  4096 mag  2 12:46 crash
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4096 feb  6 17:54 games
drwxr-xr-x 74 root root      4096 mag  3 21:19 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff     4096 ott 14  2019 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root         9 dic 25 10:08 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x 14 root syslog    4096 mag  3 21:21 log
drwx------  2 root root     16384 dic 25 10:04 lost+found
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail      4096 ott 17  2019 mail
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie  4096 ott 17  2019 metrics
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4096 ott 17  2019 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root         4 dic 25 10:08 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root      4096 mag  2 12:45 snap
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root      4096 ott 17  2019 spool
drwxrwxrwt 13 root root      4096 mag  3 21:44 tmp
```

Output of df -h (without the dev/loops)

```
File system     Dim.  Used  Avail. Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G     0    1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M  2,0M    384M   1% /run
/dev/sda3        14G   12G    2,0G  86% /
tmpfs           1,9G  103M    1,8G   6% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M     0    5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1,9G     0    1,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7        82G   28G     51G  36% /home
/dev/sda6       5,6G   46M    5,3G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda5       5,5G  4,1G    1,1G  79% /var
/dev/sda2       1,9G  137M    1,6G   8% /boot
```

How can I free up more space?

Thank you for your time

Comment: open terminal and enter the follwing code: `df -h`. Copy the output and paste it into your question by editing it. If you do not provide crucial information, no one can help you

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Empty the cache used by snapd with `sudo rm /var/lib/snapd/cache/*` might be helpful.

Comment: Ok, now it is closer, I need another 680MB though, where can I free up more space safely?

Comment: `ls` doesn't show the size of folders' contents. For this, you need to use `du` - `man du` will give an idea of what you can do with it.

Comment: To see what's taking up space in /var, from there run `du -h -d3` to give an indication of the size of some subfolders.

Comment: Now it makes sense, I'll update my question

Comment: This is exactly why normal configurations shouldn't multi-partition, especially on smallish disks. This always happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved removing some of the heaviest but safe to remove files in /var
Personally I went with /var/log and /var/cache through the use of rm, example:

```
sudo rm /var/log/* -r
```

Now there is enough space in /var to continue with the update

Comment: You should work out why /var is too small. Either you have an error making it fill up /var/log, or the partition  for /var is too small. The backside of having a /var partition is that you have to set aside enough disk space for it.

Comment: `sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk  
├─sda1   8:1    0   237M  0 part /boot/efi  
├─sda2   8:2    0   1,9G  0 part /boot  
├─sda3   8:3    0    14G  0 part /  
├─sda4   8:4    0   5,7G  0 part [SWAP]  
├─sda5   8:5    0   5,6G  0 part /var  
├─sda6   8:6    0   5,7G  0 part /tmp  
└─sda7   8:7    0  83,6G  0 part /home  `  
This are my partitions, I've taken a cue from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: You still have a problem with /var partition getting too full, so either that guide (that is 6 years old by the way) doesn't fit you, or there are a problem that makes logs grow more than expected.